# Animation of shapes in Visio via VBA

Tags: vba

Is it possible to, f.ex., rotate shapes or change different (boolean) settings like visibilty by giving commands via the object's ID or is prior selecting necessary?
As far as I got it, I have to select an deselect each item prior to change its characteristics/ data.

My code looks like this (shall produce an "animation" of blinking arrows):

```
Private Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_blinking_Click()

    rep_count = 0
    Target = 400
    blink = 0.3

    Do Until rep_count = Target
    DoEvents

    rep_count = rep_count + 1

    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(255), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Visible = True
    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(256), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(257), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    timeout (blink)

    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(256), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Visible = True
    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    timeout (blink)

    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(257), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Visible = True
    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    timeout (blink*3)

    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(255,256,257), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    timeout (blink * 0.9)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Easier way I am looking for if possible:

```
Private Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_blinking_Click()

    rep_count = 0
    Target = 400
    blink = 0.3

    Do Until rep_count = Target
    DoEvents

    rep_count = rep_count + 1

    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(255).Visible = True
    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(256).Visible = False    
    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(257).Visible = False
    timeout (blink)

    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(256).Visible = True 
    timeout (blink)
    
    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(257).Visible = False
    timeout (blink * 3)

    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(255).Visible = False
    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(256).Visible = False    
    ActiveWindow.Shapes.ID(257).Visible = False
    timeout (blink * 0.9)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try that?  What happened?

Comment: "Run-time error 438:
Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Your VBA for accessing the Visio object is all wrong. Instead of ActiveWindow.Shapes (which is not allowed) try ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(255), assuming 255 etc are correct IDs. If they aren't then you code will stop working. The .Visible attribute doesn't exist either. I think you need to download and install the Visio SDK and look at the examples therein.

Comment: Ok, will look for SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for "animated arrows" in `VBA` (as I was asking):

The function is for making a pause in between the appearance of the individual objects / shapes.

Afterwards the objects/shapes need to change their `Visibility` property to make an "blinking effect".

In my example I used three arrows with specific given names (`"Left_Arrow_1"`, etc.), here the object names must be inserted. By making a macro for inserting objects an giving them defined names, this is making things easier.

```
Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub

Sub blinking_arrows() 

rep_count = 0
target = 400
blink = 0.3

Do Until rep_count = target
DoEvents
rep_count = rep_count + 1

Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_1").Visible = True
Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_2").Visible = False
Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_3").Visible = False
timeout (blink)

Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_2").Visible = True
timeout (blink)

Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_3").Visible = True
timeout (blink * 3)

Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_1").Visible = False
Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_2").Visible = False
Sheet1.Shapes("Left_Arrow_3").Visible = False
timeout (blink * 0.9)

Loop

End Sub
```